# Greatest Common Divisor Problem X

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I having trobles troubles solving this problem.

If we know that $(a,p^2)=p$ and $(b,p^3)=p^2$, find $(ab,p^4)$ and $(a+b,p^4)$.

That is all I know. I suppose that, because this is number theory problem, all the numbers al naturals. But I don't know if $p$ is a prime number. I tried so many time and I still don't have an answer.

Comment: What's the difference between $(ab,p^4)$ and $(ab,p^4)$?

Comment: Let $q$ be a prime dividing $p$ [the case $p = 1$ is simple], and let $\gamma$ be the exponent of $q$ in the prime factorisation of $p$. What do you know about the exponent of $q$ in $(ab,p^4)$?

Comment: @Victor, Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: I don't know, It is not an hypotesis of the problem. I solved the first part of the problem, but I can't find a solution for $(a+b,p^4)$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  $p$ to be prime,

$(a,p^2)=p\implies$ the highest power of $p$ that divides $a$ is $1$

$(b,p^3)=p^2\implies$ the highest power of $p$ that divides $b$ is $2$

Comment: The OP doesn't know whether $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Can you please help me with the secon part, find the $(a+b,p^4)$ I'm not able to do that.

Comment: @VictorAmaya, We can write $a=A\cdot p, b=B\cdot p^2$ where $(A,p)=(B,p^2)=1$  $$\implies a+b=p(A+B\cdot p)$$ Now What can you say deterministically the highest power of $p$ in $$A+B\cdot p?$$

Answer (score 1):

I think i finally solved the first part.

As we know, $(a,p^2)=p$ this implies that $p|a$, and $(b,p^3)=p^2$ this implies that $p^2|b$. So, we can write this, with $p \neq 0 ,like:$
$$(\frac{a}{p},p)=1$$ and $$(\frac{b}{p^2},p)=1$$.

Hence, there is a property that says that if $(a,m)=1$ and $(b,m)=1$ $\implies$ $(ab,m)=1$.

Using this, we have:
$$(\frac{a}{p}\frac{b}{p^2},p)=1$$
$$(\frac{ab}{p^3},p)=1$$
if we multiply by $p^3$
$$(ab,p^4)=p^3$$
Is the answer to the first part.

Comment: Good job so far, it helps to abbreviate $a/p$ to $m$ and $b/p^2$ to $n$, so that $a=mp$, $b=np^2$ and $(m,p)=(n,p)=1$.  Now $a+b = mp+np^2 = p(m + np)$.  To find $(a+b,p^4)$ you need to know $(m+np,p^3)$.  What can you say about $(m+np,p)$?